# How to send emails to a users friends when the user takes a specific action?

Tags: php, events, email

I am using this script below, which works.  The only thing is it sends an email to the first email id it gets.  The rest are being ingnored.  So how do i send email to all the emails.  When i tested just the script that is pulling emails, it works, it shows all the emails.

Code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT email from
    friend_email_ids WHERE my_id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    if ($result == "")
    {
    echo "";
    }
     echo "";


   $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

   if($rows == 0)
   {
   print("");

    }
   elseif($rows > 0)
   {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {

   $email = $row['email'];


  print("");
  }

  }

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $usermail\r\n";
$subject = "$full_name added";
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "Hello, <br><br>$full_name posted someth<br><br>";
$message .= "<a href=www.domain.com/signup.php?t=&sign=>Click here.</a><br><br>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
mail("$email", "Subject: $subject",
$message, "$headers" );
echo "";
```

Comment: buddy, are you trying to write a spam script? B-)

Comment: @Oerd, according to the question title this is only in response to requested actions by friends of the recipients.

Comment: You have considerate a pool mails system, to evitate server problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your `$email` variable each time through the loop. Instead, you want to create an array, and add the email to the array each time through the loop. When finished, join the email addresses in the array with commas before sending the mail.

So before your loop (maybe after the `$rows = ...` statement), initialize a new array, like this:

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$emails = array(); /* Add this line */
```

Then each time through the loop, add the email to the array:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    array_push($emails, $row['email']);
    /* ... */
}
```

Finally, join them with commas in your email send:

```
mail(implode(',', $emails), "Subject: $subject", $message, $headers);
```

Alternatively, you can send one separate email to each user like this:

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    mail($email, "Subject: $subject", $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: ok it still doesn't work.  I don't get an error either so not sure what to check.

Comment: i am not getting any errors.  I checked all the emails, i didn't receive anything. I double checked the script and it matches your instructions.

Comment: one little issue is that the recepients are able to see which other emails have received this email.  What can i do to prevent that?

Comment: @AAA, two possibilities: (1) Send one separate email for each user instead of one combined email (this method is recommended unless you have a good reason not to). (2) Use just your email address (or any other single email address you want) in the TO field, and put all the other emails in the BCC field. To do this method, you will have to use extra headers for BCC. See here for how you would do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117091/php-mail-function-sending-mails-to-bcc-only

Comment: How do i do method #1.  I know its been a long time but i don't like the way the BCC thing is working.  For 90% of the users the email lands in junk because they are being BCC'd.  Please please point me in right direction for method #1.  Thanks Ben!

Comment: @AAA, you can just loop through the $emails array and send a separate email for each one. I updated my answer and added a part at the bottom showing how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try it as soon as i get the new ftp info. Will let you know.

Comment: OK that worked but that gave me another problem.  Now it will only work if i choose one email address to send to.  If i select more than 1 then it doesn't work.

Comment: @AAA, I don't quite follow. Please ask another question with your new problem details. That way other people can help you too.

Comment: ;) OK no problems.  Will do.  Thanks for your help thus far. I will pay it forward in the best way possible! thanks again.

Comment: @AAA, I just noticed you have a bounty on this question but haven't awarded it to me even though you marked my answer as accepted. Is my answer incomplete? (Note that the problem you mentioned in your last comment was related to your sql query, a completely unrelated question, and I answered your sql question there).

Comment: BTW, the answer to your question I was referring to in my last comment is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10354657/480943

Comment: Hey sorry i didn't check out your previous comment.  I am unsure man.  I am frustrated at this point.  I am a new PHP guy and i am trying to make sense of what you mentioned but without a script for me to try out i am having hard time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $usermail\r\n";
$subject = "$full_name added";
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "Hello, <br><br>$full_name posted someth<br><br>";
$message .= "<a href='www.domain.com/signup.php?t=&sign='>Click here.</a><br><br>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT email from friend_email_ids WHERE my_id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   mail($row['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
   // for debugging purposes, uncomment the following line
   // echo $row['email']
}
```

Changes:

- cleaned up PHP code (removed unused instructions, remove second query which doesn't do anything, removed string vars in `"` etc.)
- corrected HTML link in the email message (it had no quotes on the `href` attribute)
- loop through results to send email for each `$row`

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work. It works just like the old script, it only sends if its going to one person if more than one person then it doesn't send at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am attaching code for sending multiple mails and integrating it with your existing code.

You just need to copy paste this code in your page and upload it on some server to test for its workability. I have already tested on my server and it gives multiple mails.

$email = array();

```
$sql = "SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT email from friend_email_ids WHERE my_id = '".$id."' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $email[] = $row['email'];
}


/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r($email);
exit;
*/
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $usermail\r\n";

$subject = "$full_name added";
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "Hello, <br><br>$full_name posted this mail<br><br>";
$message .= "<a href='www.aadinathtech.com/index.php'>Click here.</a><br><br>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

foreach($email as $key=>$val) {
    mail($val, "Subject: $subject", $message, "$headers" );
    echo "<br />Mail has been sent to $val<br /><br />";
}
```

Please revert me back if you still find any problem.

Comment: Thanks.  But it doesn't work.  It works just like the old script, it only sends if its going to one person if more than one person then it doesn't send at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a small modification by moving the last block of code inside your loop.
Try this:

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

   if($rows == 0)
   {
   print("");

    }
   elseif($rows > 0)
   {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {

   $email = $row['email'];
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
   $headers .= "From: $usermail\r\n";
   $subject = "$full_name added";
   $message = "<html><body>";
   $message .= "Hello, <br><br>$full_name posted someth<br><br>";
   $message .= "<a href=www.domain.com/signup.php?t=&sign=>Click here.</a><br><br>";
   $message .= "</body></html>";
   mail("$email", "Subject: $subject",
   $message, "$headers" );

  print("");
  }

  }


echo "";
```