# How to send email to multiple email addresses?

Tags: php, email

I have this form that is working perfectly except that it won't send emails to multiple people.  It only sends it to one person.  How do i fix this? I want to be able to send each individual a individual email with their email address in the to field regardless if that same email was sent to other users.

Update: I did a print $email; and if i select only one email it would print it and then if i  more than 1 then it wouldn't print anything.  So that means its not detecting more than 1 email.

```
     $sql = "SELECT email from
    friend_email_ids WHERE my_id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    if ($result == "")
    {
    echo "";
    }
     echo "";


   $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
   $emails = array();

   if($rows == 0)
   {
   print("");

    }
   elseif($rows > 0)
   {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {

   array_push($emails, $row['email']);


  print("");
  }

  }

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $usermail\r\n";
$subject = "$full_name added";
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "Hello, <br><br>$full_name posted someth<br><br>";
$message .= "<a href=www.domain.com/signup.php?t=&sign=>Click here.</a><br><br>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
 foreach ($emails as $email) {
mail($email, "Subject: $subject", $message, $headers);
   }


   echo "";
```

Comment: What's with all of the printing of blank strings?

Comment: Hey Amber.  Not sure.  I always had it there.  I am sort of new to PHP.

Comment: @micha CC will not work because i don't want other peoples email addresses to be shown.  I want it to look like it was only sent to them.  Think of facebook email notifications.

Answer (score 1):

in PHP, you usually have some code that will look like

```
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
```

and you can set multiple email recipients like so

```
    $to  = 'one@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
    $to .= 'two@example.com';
```

The comma and the .= will allow multiple email recipients.

For more than two, you would use

```
    $to  = 'one@example.com' . ', ';
    $to .= 'two@example.com' . ', ';
    $to .= 'three@example.com';
```

To do this automatically, you could set up a foreach with a twist for the last entry in the array

```
    foreach($email as $to) {
    $lastone = next($email)===FALSE;
    $to .= $email . ', ';       
    if(!$lastone){
    $to .= $email;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  But in my case the email ids are being drawn from the database as you can see above, I won't be able to control how many there are so this won't work for me.

Comment: you can simply join the emails like this `implode(",", $emails)`, and I think others can still see the email addresses if you use this method.

Comment: @candy yes.  i actually used that before but again like you mentioned it doesn't suit my requirements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` to join the emails together separated by commas. By populating a comma-separated value in the "to" field it will automatically send to multiple recipients:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISINCT `email` SEPARATOR ',') from
    friend_email_ids WHERE my_id='$id'"
    GROUP BY `email;
```

Group Concat MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

PHP Doc explaining multiple email recipients in `mail()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks.  But will it still work if there is only one person that receives notification?

Comment: Yes, though a hanging comma shouldn't affect the sending to any recipient.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I actually integrated the CONCAT but it still gives me the same problem.

Comment: Your bigger problem is that $email in your code above is an *array*, not a string. Don't use `array_push`, or `join` with commas.

Comment: OK understood.  I removed the arrays.  But despite that it still won't work if more than 1 is selected.

Comment: According to the php doc (and testing on my end) any comma separated list in $email will send to multiple recipients. I would check your error log and/or sendmail.

Comment: OK, just checked error logs and nothing there gives me an error about this.

Comment: Please do a var_dump of $email and verify what it is outputting prior to the mail() statement. Paste results here.

Comment: Ok here it is; if i select one person then the var_dump is: string(0) ""     if i do multiple it says NULL

Comment: There's a problem with your query - it is not returning what you expect... in this case with "one person" it returns a blank string, and with multiple, it returns NULL. At this point your issues look to extend beyond the scope of your original "how to" in the question and now become troubleshooting your original query.

Comment: But i wonder how it can still send it correctly to that one person that is selected. i am testing it and it seems it sends it correctly.

Comment: IT seems adding the CONCAT is printing empty or null strings.  You are right, i am new to PHP so thats why i am running into these issues.

Comment: Please note that you should use GROUP_CONCAT with the GROUP function as part of my original suggestion. Let's move this to chat if the comment thread must continue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10578/discussion-between-aaa-and-philwinkle)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM friend_email_ids WHERE my_id='$id'";
```

You are only receiving one email address because you are only *selecting* one email address, from the user with the id stored in `$id`. To fix this, you have to select all the ids you need. First, you need to make sure that you have a variable called `$ids` that stores a comma-separated list of ids. Then change your query to:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM friend_email_ids WHERE my_id IN ($ids)";
```

If your ids are integers there is no need to quote them like you did in your original query. If they are strings, then make sure you quote them in the comma-separated list. If you don't know how to make your `$ids` variable as I described, then you need to read some php tutorials. It's basic stuff.

Otherwise, your script should work. But as someone pointed out in the comments, you have a whole lot of superfluous code with blank strings, you can remove most of it.