# Send mail to multiple recipient

Tags: php, sql, arrays, email

i have already research on using the mail() to send to multiple recipient's but i just cant get it to work. What im trying to do is, for every order that i have, order 1,2,3, each having their own email addresses, when i change their order status from pending to confirm, the mail() will use that id to refer to the db table and send the email of those 3 orders. But for my case, it mailed just the latest order which is order 3.
This is the form that i use to change the order status.

```
<form action="results-action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>


<table id ="table_id" class="display">

<thead>

<tr><td><h2>Pending Order</h2></td></tr>

<tr>
<th scope="col">Order ID</th>
<th scope="col"> </th>
<th scope="col">Name</th>
<th scope="col">Address</th>
<th scope="col">Product Name</th>
<th scope="col">Produt Quantity</th>
<th scope="col">Price</th>
<th scope="col">Order status</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" value='<?=$row['virtuemart_order_id']?>' name="orderid" id="virtuemart_order_id"></td>
<td><input type="hidden" value='<?=$row['virtuemart_product_id']?>' name="productid" id="virtuemart_product_id"></td>
<td><?=$row['first_name']?></td>
<td><?=$row['address_1']?></td>
<td><?=$row['order_item_name']?></td>

<td><?=$row['product_quantity']?></td>

<td><?=$row['product_final_price'] ?></td>
<td><select name='change[<?=$row['virtuemart_order_id']?>]'>
<option value='C'> Confirmed</option>

<option value='X'> Cancelled</option></select></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>



<fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Update status" name="update status"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>



</form>
```

This is the php, using the order id from the form to select the email addresses.

```
<?php
$orderid = $_POST['orderid'];


// build SQL statement to select email addresses
$query3 = "SELECT email from ruj3d_virtuemart_order_userinfos where virtuemart_order_id = '$orderid'";


// execute SQL statement
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link)); 


$subject = "Order confirmed by Home and decor";
$message = "Hello! This is a message to inform that your order has been confirmed";
$from = "107496@myrp.edu.sg";
$headers = "From: $from";

while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){ 

$addresses[] = $row3['email'];

}

$to = implode(",", $addresses);



mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: separating recipents with comma is right, what does var_dump($to) give you?

Comment: I recomment you to use a Mailer-class like swiftmailer. I had the problem that some provider like gmail or hotmail refused my emails sent with the simple mail() function, because parts of the mail were missing. Such a mailer-class will handle these problems for you...

Comment: btw, you should escape your orderid

Comment: @m02ph3u5 im using my own email for testing on order 8 and 9. var_dump($to). it shows: string(51) " ahmadXXX@hotmail.com, ahmadXXX@hotmail.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong `$_POST` field to select your email addresses.

The form generated by the first php file contains a table, with each row containing an input field named `'orderid'`. But the field you are really interested in is the `select` input value of each row. These are all stored in one single array named `change` in the `$_POST` array.

Here's an example of how `$_POST` could be initialized to correspond to the select values being returned by the form:

```
$_POST['change'] = array('id1' => 'C', 'id2' => 'X' /*, 'id3' => ... */ );
```

So you need to:

- get the array returned by the form in `$_POST`,
- filter out the entries which aren't equal to 'C',
- keep the keys of these entries,
- escape them to sanitize them,

You should replace the beginning of your php file with the following, which does as explained above.

This first version doesn't sanitize the entries:

```
<?php

function confirmed($v) { return ($v == 'C'); }

// pick the rows in your form table which have been set as confirmed, and use the keys 
$orderid = implode(',', array_keys(array_filter($_POST['change'],'confirmed')));

// build SQL statement to select email addresses
$query3 = "SELECT email FROM ruj3d_virtuemart_order_userinfos WHERE virtuemart_order_id IN (".$orderid.")";

// etc.
```

This one does sanitization:

```
<?php

function confirmed($v) { return ($v == 'C'); }

// pick the rows in your form table which have been set as confirmed, and use the keys 
$orderid = implode(',', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', 
                                  array_keys(array_filter($_POST['change'],'confirmed'))));


// build SQL statement to select email addresses
$query3 = "SELECT email FROM ruj3d_virtuemart_order_userinfos WHERE virtuemart_order_id IN (".$orderid.")";

// etc.
```

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117091/php-mail-function-sending-mails-to-bcc-only) for the use of BCC with the `mail()` function.

Comment: ouh ok. then refering to my codes above, should i remove my implode??

while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){ 

$addresses[] = $row3['email'];

}

$to = implode(",", $addresses);

Comment: idk y but there's an error, check sql version you are using and syntax error ',)' at line 1?? i try to ctrl+f that syntax but nothing.

Comment: but i think i understood your codes, id1 is a key and the C is a value. Use the function to detect if the value is C then take the key, which is the id. Then select the db table. Is there any other way to do it? Also before implementing your code, i tried to echo out the $orderid and it just shows the latest order id. No wonder it only send an email to only that order email, it ignores the rest of the orders..

Comment: This is the error when i try to use var_dump and ure codes. "string(2) ",," You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',)' at line 1"

Comment: array(2) { [8]=> string(1) "C" [9]=> string(1) "C" }

Comment: yup, the array filer: if order 8 and 9 confirmed: array(2) { [8]=> string(1) "C" [9]=> string(1) "C" }// if order 8 cancelled but 9 confirmed: array(1) { [9]=> string(1) "C" }

Comment: yup, ive tried ure edited code. If both are confirmed, it only send email to the latest order, order 9. But no email for order 8.

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($addresses);` right before the `mail()` instruction?

Comment: since order 8 and 9 are for testing, ive been using my own email.
array(2) { [0]=> string(25) " ahmadXXX@hotmail.com" [1]=> string(25) " ahmadXXX@hotmail.com" }

Comment: which i dont understand. supposedly i should receive 2 mail since i can see two of my mail after var_dump($addresses); but i only receive one mail.

Comment: on second thought, use the `Bcc` header field as explained in another answer to handle the multiple emails: there are issues on several platforms when using the `$to` parameter, and you will have to use that solution anyway to hide the list of emails.

Comment: see [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117091/php-mail-function-sending-mails-to-bcc-only).

Comment: ok, will do. Also idk if this will help but i tried to var_dump($to). it shows: string(51) " ahmadXXX@hotmail.com, ahmadXXX@hotmail.com"

Comment: erm hi, when i choose the option cancelled for all the orders, it shows an error sql version and syntax error. Should i make a cancelled function too?

Comment: @AhmadMaslan Please avoid extended discussion in the comments, if you have a further question then please start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Cc` to your headers, its part of the reason [Headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) where created:

```
$headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: ".$secondEmail.', '.$thirdEmail . "\r\n"
```

Comment: You shouldn't attempt using `mail()` in 2012. Use one of the various solid libraries that have already solved all these problems, securely, for years.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a space here after the comma, like so:
`$to = implode(", ", $addresses);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Select
  email 
From 
  ruj3d_virtuemart_order_userinfos 
Where 
  virtuemart_order_id = '$orderid'
```

Do

```
Select
  email 
From 
  ruj3d_virtuemart_order_userinfos 
Where 
  virtuemart_order_id In ($orderid)
```

(I might have the PHP wrong, I'm just going on the sql statement. If $orderid doesn't look like a comma separated list when you submit more than one, then you need to make it one)

Actually, don't just do that, also learn about SQL injection, and replace the deprecated mysqli library with PDO especially [PDO::Prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Oh, and if these are different customers, don't send mail in the to field, your customers won't appreciate you sending their email addresses to each other.