# php mail bcc multiple

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send multiple recipients in Bcc.http://overseascareer.net/course-details.php?id=2#semi I have a text field in which when i enter single recipients the mail will send. But, what i want to do is when i will enter multiple recipients with comma, all recipients will go in BCC not in TO.

I am trying this code to do this task:

```
$to = $input_value;
$subject = $suject;
$txt = $res[$content_id];

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <'.$fromid.'>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $to) . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

Comment: What unexpected thing is happening in your code?  It isn't clear from your example what your problem is.

Comment: i am just sharing a link. kindly open it. At the bottom of the page you find a text field. when i enter a single mail id in this box and click on submit the active tab will mail on same id. but when i will enter multiple mail id in box all mail id will show in "TO". what i want to do is when i will enter multiple mail id all mail will go in BCC.

Comment: my problem is with this code i can send mail on multiple recipients. but all mail ids is showing in "TO". But i want to send mail in BCC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mail function: Sending mails to BCC only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117091/php-mail-function-sending-mails-to-bcc-only)

Answer (score 0):

The mail function does not require a to field so you can supply `null`.

In order to only send out to the emails specified in the BCC header you should modify your code as follows:

```
$to = $input_value;
$subject = $suject;
$txt = $res[$content_id];

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <'.$fromid.'>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $to) . "\r\n";

mail(null,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

BTW `$to` should be an array of the email addresses to which you will deliver.

**EDIT**
Found a duplicate question with exactly the same requirement. Check it out: [php mail function: Sending mails to BCC only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117091/php-mail-function-sending-mails-to-bcc-only)

Answer (score 0):

Try This one its work for me.

```
$to = $input_value;
$subject = $suject;
$txt = $res[$content_id];

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers

$bcc = implode(",", $to);

$headers .= 'From: <'.$fromid.'>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: '. $bcc . "\r\n";

mail('',$subject,$txt,$headers);
```